# Capital sigma missing in Euler font

Tags: fonts, incompatibility

I'm using the Euler font in my equations and it appears that the capital Sigma symbol is missing (a dot is displayed in its place).  It appears to be caused by a conflict between euler or eulervm, fontenc and breqn. Here's a minimal example. Any suggestions?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{eulervm}
\usepackage{breqn}
\begin{document}
$$
\Sigma_i
$$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you add a minimal example? Both `euler` and `eulervm` have a working `$\Sigma$` for me...

Comment: very strange.  i've just run testfont with eurm10 and euex10, and both the capital sigma and two forms of sum are there; the version accessed is from tex live 2010.  please provide a minimum working example to show what package(s) you're using.

Comment: I've edited the question to include a minimal example and the conflicting packages.

Comment: I've formatted the code sample in your question by indenting it with four spaces in front of each line. You can do that by selecting the code and pressing the `{}` button.

Comment: It's clearly a bug in **breqn** that redefines `\Sigma`.

Comment: @egreg -- in fact, *breqn* redefines not only `\Sigma` but the whole greek alphabet, making the obvious adjustment of reversing the order of the `\usepackage` commands inoperative.  i think this is not a bug, but a design decision, and would have to ask the maintainer of *breqn* about it, if it's not obvious from the `.dtx` file.  it's not possible to ask the original author as he died in 2003.  however, redefinitions of the greek letters were in a 2002 version of breqn, although in a separate file, not in `breqn.sty' itself.

Comment: @barbara it looks like your comment solves the problem. If you could add this as an answer?

Comment: @Seamus -- it looks like @Gonzalo's answer already sets out the important information, so i'll hold off on posting an answer since he has included more details than i dug up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that

```
\DeclareFlexSymbol{\Gamma}  {Var}{latin}{00}
\DeclareFlexSymbol{\Delta}  {Var}{latin}{01}
\DeclareFlexSymbol{\Theta}  {Var}{latin}{02}
\DeclareFlexSymbol{\Lambda} {Var}{latin}{03}
\DeclareFlexSymbol{\Xi}     {Var}{latin}{04}
\DeclareFlexSymbol{\Pi}     {Var}{latin}{05}
\DeclareFlexSymbol{\Sigma}  {Var}{latin}{06}
\DeclareFlexSymbol{\Upsilon}{Var}{latin}{07}
\DeclareFlexSymbol{\Phi}    {Var}{latin}{08}
\DeclareFlexSymbol{\Psi}    {Var}{latin}{09}
\DeclareFlexSymbol{\Omega}  {Var}{latin}{0A}
\DeclareFlexSymbol{0}{Var}{latin}{30}
\DeclareFlexSymbol{1}{Var}{latin}{31}
\DeclareFlexSymbol{2}{Var}{latin}{32}
\DeclareFlexSymbol{3}{Var}{latin}{33}
\DeclareFlexSymbol{4}{Var}{latin}{34}
\DeclareFlexSymbol{5}{Var}{latin}{35}
\DeclareFlexSymbol{6}{Var}{latin}{36}
\DeclareFlexSymbol{7}{Var}{latin}{37}
\DeclareFlexSymbol{8}{Var}{latin}{38}
\DeclareFlexSymbol{9}{Var}{latin}{39}
```

after loading **breqn** is sufficient. Thanks to Gonzalo for providing the clue.

Answer (score 6):

As barbara beeton mentioned in a comment, `flexysym` and `eulervm` don't cooperate. A possible workaroung is to use the `savesym` package: the idea is to load `breqn` and then rename the conflicting symbols (the whole Greek alphabet and some others) using `\savesymbol`. Once this is done, `eulervm` can be safely loaded.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{savesym}
\savesymbol{Gamma}
\savesymbol{Delta}
\savesymbol{Theta}
\savesymbol{Lambda}
\savesymbol{Xi}
\savesymbol{Pi}
\savesymbol{Sigma}
\savesymbol{Upsilon}
\savesymbol{Phi}
\savesymbol{Psi}
\savesymbol{Omega}
\savesymbol{alpha}
\savesymbol{beta}
\savesymbol{gamma}
\savesymbol{delta}
\savesymbol{epsilon}
\savesymbol{zeta}
\savesymbol{eta}
\savesymbol{theta}
\savesymbol{iota}
\savesymbol{kappa}
\savesymbol{lambda}
\savesymbol{mu}
\savesymbol{nu}
\savesymbol{xi}
\savesymbol{pi}
\savesymbol{rho}
\savesymbol{sigma}
\savesymbol{tau}
\savesymbol{upsilon}
\savesymbol{phi}
\savesymbol{chi}
\savesymbol{psi}
\savesymbol{omega}
\savesymbol{varepsilon}
\savesymbol{vartheta}
\savesymbol{varpi}
\savesymbol{varphi}
\savesymbol{infty}
\savesymbol{ldotp}
\usepackage{eulervm}

\begin{document}

\[ \Sigma_1\Delta_2 \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

A more definitive solution would be to create a support file in `flexysim` for `eulervm`; this doen't seem to be so hard according to the documentation of `breqn`:

> If you find that a particular math
>   font package doesn’t work then please
>   see implementation in `flexisym.dtx`
>   for how to create a support file—it is
>   easier than one might think.
>   Contributions welcome.

Comment: I lost symbol  when I use `\leqslant`  with your code. How can I get that symbol?